# Function scope is lost in returned methods when strigifying/parsing js objects with JSON

Tags: javascript, json, function, scope

I have such a bit crazy example, but it looks like a good exercise for those who are experts in javascript function scopes:

```
(function (global) {
  // our module number one
  var body = function () {
    var someVar = 'some test text';
    return {
        method: function () {
            return someVar; // this will undefined when call this method in second module
        }
    };
  };
  var f = new Function([' return (', body, ')();'].join(''));
  global.r = f();
})(window);

(function (global) {
  // our module two
  var body = function () {
    // dep variable is injected on the fly with `new Function`
    dep.method(); // will throw `Reference Error: someVar is not defined`
  };

  // helper to propertly transform functions in JSON.stringify
  function transformFuncs (key, val) {
    if (typeof val === 'function') {
        return val.toString().replace(/(\t|\n|\r)/gm, '').replace(/("|')/gm, '\\"');
    }
    return val;
  }
  // injecting our first module inside
  var vars = ['var ', 'dep', ' = JSON.parse(\'', JSON.stringify(global.r, transformFuncs), '\', function (key, value) { if (value && typeof value === "string" && value.substr(0,8) == "function") { var startBody = value.indexOf("{") + 1; var endBody = value.lastIndexOf("}"); var startArgs = value.indexOf("(") + 1; var endArgs = value.indexOf(")"); return new Function(value.substring(startArgs, endArgs), value.substring(startBody, endBody)); } return value; });'].join('');
  // as variable
  var f2 = new Function([vars, ' return (', body, ')();'].join(''));
  global.r2 = f2();
})(window);
```

If you'll run this code somewhere you'll see an exception thrown `ReferenceError: someVar is not defined`.

So basically what's happening here - we create some module and then trying to inject it inside another one as variable. Function that is used in `JSON.parse` to correctly get stringified functions looks like this (if you're curious):

```
function (key, value) { 
  if (value && typeof value === "string" && value.substr(0,8) == "function") { 
    var startBody = value.indexOf("{") + 1; 
    var endBody = value.lastIndexOf("}"); 
    var startArgs = value.indexOf("(") + 1; 
    var endArgs = value.indexOf(")"); 
    return new Function(value.substring(startArgs, endArgs), value.substring(startBody, endBody)); 
  } 
  return value; 
}
```

So.. the question is it possible to workaround such scope behavior? As I understand `global.r` is assigned with `f` result in one scope, but resulted object with `method` function is not saving the variable instance because while JSON parsing another scope is created for that function.

Any ideas?

**P.S.** Please don't ask why I need this :) just think about possible solutions. **The main idea is to somehow inject module number one** (look top `body` var) **as variable inside second module** (`body` var of second function) **saving the original scope of methods that are returned**.

Thanks!

Comment: No, it's not possible. Since you are converting a function to a string, you are loosing the environment it was created in. This information is not accessible at runtime, so there is no way to serialize it somehow. You could make some progress with static analysis, but that only works for values contained in the source, not created at runtime. So it's probably too much of an effort to go this route at all.

Comment: Please explain WTH these `new Function` things are necessary for. At least `f` could be completedly omitted, I'm not sure about `f2` but I guess it's not required as well. Please remove them from the code for simplification, or comment what they do (especially that one-liner in `f2`).

Comment: @Bergi this example is just a simplified version of the codebase that I'm working on. Don't pay to much attention on it. `new Function` things are needed because in my case (that is ommited in the example) I'm for-looping through a hashmap of different modules and saving them as variables string which is then injected.

Comment: Well, yes, the solution is just not to store strings in that hashmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to workaround such scope behavior?

No. Scopes are inaccessible from outside, and they are necessarily lost on serialisation of a function. You can only stringify "pure" functions like `body` that do not reference any free variables.

That's also the reason why the JSON format does not include functions.

> The main idea is to somehow inject module number one as variable inside second module saving the original scope of methods that are returned.

Inject the reference, not a string. Dependency injection is no magic, all kinds of module loaders for JavaScript do it.

Comment: the problem in referencing that I cannot solve is that I cannot inject some module inside other one as variable (keeping the name of dependency for var name inside second module)

Comment: Inject it as a function parameter. But maybe I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: I mean that I have for example a hashmap of dependencies for some module. I would like to inject every dependency inside module function as variable with name of hash property and **not** as function argument (take a look at second ``body`` - ``r`` is injected as var inside on the fly with ``new Function``).

Comment: I've updated the code of example - now it's `dep` for more clearance.

Comment: I just thought that it will be possible with ``this['myVarName']`` inside function.

Comment: But it's again.. I need to assign this vars looping through each of dep.

Comment: There's not so much difference between a variable (namable via `eval`) and a function parameter (namable via `new Function`) - you're free to use either for getting arbitrarily named identifiers in a scope. You just need to do `var dep = modulesHash["r"]` instead of `var dep = eval(stringifiedModules["r"])`

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot, just did it in that way. Sometimes we overcomplicate some things :)